# Can I batch rename my materials with the name listed as the base color with python?

Tags: materials

So I have 1000s of old exported models but each of their materials are named standardmaterial.00x. However, when I click on each individual material the BASE COLOR has the correct name of the material. Can I make my life easier and produce a script that will pull the base color name from each material and assign that as the name of the material? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Save beforehand in case it messes up.

```
import bpy


def find_base_color_node(mat):
    try:
        for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
                break

        return node.inputs["Base Color"].links[0].from_node
        
    except Exception:
        return None


def get_node_name(node):
    try:
        if node.label: return node.label
        return node.image.name

    except Exception:
        return None


mat_names = [
    mat.name for mat in bpy.data.materials
    if mat.name.startswith("Standardmaterial")
]

for mat_name in mat_names:
    mat = bpy.data.materials[mat_name]
    node = find_base_color_node(mat)
    new_name = get_node_name(node)
    if new_name:
        mat.name = new_name
```

Comment: Success! Thank you.